# Handle generic listeners of event bus in Kotlin

Tags: android, generics, events, kotlin, jvm

My goal is to implement very simple event bus in Kotlin without any 3rd party libraries. I accomplished that with the code below.

```
class EventListener<T>(
    val owner: Any,
    val event: Class<T>,
    val callback: (T) -> Unit
)

interface IEventBus {
    fun <T> subscribe(owner: Any, event: Class<T>, callback: (T) -> Unit)
    fun unsubscribe(owner: Any)
    fun <T> push(event: T)
}

class EventBus : IEventBus {
    private val _listeners = mutableListOf<EventListener<*>>()

    override fun <T> subscribe(owner: Any, event: Class<T>, callback: (T) -> Unit) {
        val listener = EventListener(owner, event, callback)
        _listeners.add(listener)
    }

    override fun unsubscribe(owner: Any) {
        _listeners.removeAll {
            it.owner == owner
        }
    }

    override fun <T> push(event: T) {
        _listeners.forEach { listener ->
            try {
                val l = listener as EventListener<T> // is always a success
                l.callback(event)                    // throws an exception if can't handle the event
            } catch (ex: Exception) { }
        }
    }
}
```

And then the usage would be like this:

```
// register listener
bus.subscribe(this, String::class.java) {
    print(it)
}
// push an event (from somewhere else in the project)
bus.push("Hello world!")
```

It works and is completely usable, however I am not satisfied with it... Casting **listener as EventListener** will always return something and then if **l.callback(event)** can't handle the event type it will throw an exception. So if there are many listeners subscribed then it will generate many unwanted exceptions that will just be ignored.

I would prefer doing some kind of check first, like:

```
if (listener is EventListener<T>)
    listener.callback(event)
```

But I found out that JVM loses information about the generic types after the compilation. I also found out that it can be bypassed using kotlin's **inline** and **reified**, however those can not be used on a method that comes from an interface...

So my question is do you know any more elegant way to handle such generic problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are already exposing the class of the event (`EventListener#event`) you can use `isInstance()` to check if the class is assignment-compatible with the instance of your event.

So, instead of:

```
if (listener is EventListener<T>)
    listener.callback(event)
```

you can do:

```
if (listener.event.isInstance(event)) {
    // The cast is safe since you checked if the event can be received by the listener.
    (listener as EventListener<T>).callback(event)
}
```

**Primitives**

If you want to support `T` with primitive types too, you can change `Class<T>` to `KClass<T>` or check the instance manually on each primitive type (e.g. `event is Int`, `event is Long`).

Comment: However it seems to have a problem with Int.

Int::class.java.isInstance(5) // false

Comment: @DawidGrajewski This happens because `Int` in Kotlin can both refer to the primitive Java `int` and to the boxed Java `Integer`. If you want to support primitives, you have two possibilities: replace `Class<T>` with `KClass<T>` or check if `event` is assignable to the primitive types. E.g. `event is Int`, `event is Long`. If you can, obviously I recommend you to change `Class` to `KClass` since it will avoid you all the checks on primitive types.

Comment: Thank you once more! That closes the whole thing for me. Have a good one : )

Answer (score 0):

The documentation of [kotlinx.coroutines.flow.SharedFlow](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/-shared-flow/) contains a simple example:

> SharedFlow is useful for broadcasting events that happen inside an
> application to subscribers that can come and go. For example, the
> following class encapsulates an event bus that distributes events to
> all subscribers in a rendezvous manner, suspending until all
> subscribers process each event:

```
class EventBus {
    private val _events = MutableSharedFlow<Event>() // private mutable shared flow
    val events = _events.asSharedFlow() // publicly exposed as read-only shared flow

    suspend fun produceEvent(event: Event) {
        _events.emit(event) // suspends until all subscribers receive it
    }
}
```

Besides, the [corresponding Android documentation](https://developer.android.com/kotlin/flow/stateflow-and-sharedflow) is useful, too.